# Avoiding duplicates in result list with JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem with `Group`s containing `GroupElement`s.

For example, with this data :

- Group A contains elements 1,2,3
- Group B contains elements 4,5,6

I try to list the `Group` and expect to get 2 `Group` with 3 `GroupElement` in each `Group`.

Instead, each `Group` is duplicated. I actually obtain 6 `Group`:

- Group A contains elements 1,2,3
- Group A contains elements 1,2,3
- Group A contains elements 1,2,3
- Group B contains elements 4,5,6
- Group B contains elements 4,5,6
- Group B contains elements 4,5,6

My guess is that a `Group` is rebuilt for each `GroupElement`.

I searched on SO and found that the problem could come from the `equals()/hashCode()` definition or from the way the request is written so I give you both.

I have this mapping :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "xxx")
public class Group {

  ...

  @JsonBackReference
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "group")
  private List<GroupElement> groupElements = Lists.newArrayList();

  //Getters & Setters

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }

    if (o == null || !o.getClass().equals(getClass())) {
      return false;
    }

   return getId() != null && getId().equals(((HasId) o).getId());
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return getId() != null ? getId().hashCode() : super.hashCode();
  }
}
```

I request groups like this :

```
public List<Group> listFull() {
  CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
  CriteriaQuery<Group> query = cb.createQuery(Group.class);
  Root<Group> group = query.from(Group.class);
  group.fetch(Group_.groupElements, JoinType.LEFT);
  return em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
}
```

I can fix it with an intermediate Set but I ask this question in order to find a better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set ResultTransformer to you (Hibernate)Criteria and you will get result without duplicates:

```
Session session = getSession();
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(clazz);
criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

If you are using JPA, try this:

```
CriteriaQuery<Group> query = cb.createQuery(Group.class);
query.distinct(true);
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I asked the question with `hibernate` in the title but I would prefer a pure JPA solution. Do you have an equivalent in JPA?

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle i updated my answer. I hope it helps