# Duplicate results with Hibernate, Spring, MySQL 5.7, Lombok

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have simple code like:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true, timeout = 10)
public List<MyClass> findThem() {

    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(MyClass.class);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<MyClass> theList = criteria.list();
    return theList;
}
```

When I use this for the query, I get back 942 items, with duplicated items in the list.  I don't see the pattern about which ones are duplicated just yet.

If I query with DB directly, I get back 138 records.  138 is the correct number of results:

`SELECT count(*) FROM theschema.MY_CLASS;`

I tried using the class with and without Lombok's `@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude="id")` on `MyClass` and also just not including any `equals()` implementation, thinking this was the cause - but no luck.

I've recently upgraded from MySQL 5.6 to MySQL 5.7.17 but I'm still on Hibernate 4.3.8.Final and HikariCP 2.5.1.  The query has no `WHERE` clauses or anything very complicated.  It may not matter, but I'm on Spring 4.3.3.RELEASE with mysql-connector-java 5.1.39.

Any other suggestions where to look?  I'm going to turn on more debug logging and take a closer look in the meantime.

**Update**:

I'm able to [correct this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24865294/avoiding-duplicates-in-result-list-with-jpa/24865364#24865364) with         `criteria.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);` but not sure why it's now necessary.

**Update 2**

Here's `MyClass`.  It has more basic properties, but I excerpted them for brevity.  Some of the names are renamed for privacy reasons.

```
import base.domain.model.Persistable;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.*;

@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_CLASS")
public class MyClass implements Persistable {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Id
    @Column(name = "MY_CLASS_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private ClassB classb;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CLASS_C_ID")
    private ClassC classC;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Transient
    private Integer daysOpen;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CLASS_D_ID")
    private ClassD classD;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NotEmpty
    private String briefDescription;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(length = 1000)
    private String details;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "COMPANY_ID")
    private Company company;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Transient
    private BigDecimal cost;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinTable(name = "MY_CLASS_TAG",
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_MY_CLASS_TAG_REQUEST"),
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "MY_CLASS_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "TAG_ID"))
    private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>(10);

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinTable(name = "MY_CLASS_ASSIGNEE",
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_MY_CLASS_ASSIGNEE"),
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "MY_CLASS_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ASSIGNEE_ID"))
    private Set<Account> assignees = new HashSet<>(0);

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "myClass")
    private List<MyClassHistory> historyList = new ArrayList<>(1);

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

**Update 3:**

I am also able to get the correct results using HQL (abridged) without the result transformer:

```
    String hql = "from MyClass myClass";
    Query q = getSession().createQuery(hql);
    List<MyClass> myClasses = q.list();
    return myClasses;
```

Going to compare the SQL output for each (there's a lot of output to try to understand).

Comment: Does your myclass has one many relationship to another entity. If yes, then it might give you duplicate records via hibernate if the fetch type is defined as eager in one to many relationship.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560239/is-it-valid-for-hibernate-list-to-return-duplicates

Comment: @PushpendraPal good thought, but no EAGER fetch types.

Comment: Find the SQL commands that are issued.  This may give you (or us) a clue of what is going wrong.

Comment: @bphilipnyc do you have any one to many relationships from your MyClass to some other class ?

Comment: Which version of mysql-connector-xyz.jar are you using (now/before)?

Comment: @MWeisner mysql-connector-java 5.1.39

Comment: Can you post MyClass.java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there must be some join happening in the query, which increases resultset and hence your count,often I face similar issue, you can try to take data in Set instead of list, or observe the actual query fired in DB.

Comment: As posted, MyClass uses Sets except for the last property - and I need that to be a List since it must allow duplicates.  The SQL query is really involved, but will try to get to it.